# css html background gradient

Tags: css, gradient

i found this css to create background gradient

```
html {
    background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
}
```

however it only creates a small bar and I want it to go from top to bottom of entire page could someone tell me how to modify it to make the it work the way I want it to or even if it is possible

ohh yeah and it repeats for soeme reason

Comment: As a side note, new Webkit browsers no longer use the `-webkit-gradient()` syntax, but rather the more standard-like `-webkit-linear-gradient()`. You can keep the old syntax for backwards compatibility, just remember to add the new syntax in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your page is too short. Either add `min-height: 100%;`, or flesh out your page a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the HTML height:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that demo I found it most useful as I had not used "html" as the selector before :)